# Como comprobar si hay espacios en una cadena en C

Tags: c, fgets

Tras pedir que se ingrese una cadena, en caso de haber algun espacio o tabulador tiene que aparecer un mensaje diciendo "cadena no valida". Como puedo comprobar si los hay?

Comment: Las preguntas sin código incluido no son bien recibidas en stackoverflow. [Como formular una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: Puedes utilizar strchr(cadena, ' ') retorna NULL si no hay espacio o si lo hubiera retorna el puntero al inicio del espacio. Igual para tabulación strchr(cadena,'\t')

Answer (score 1):

segun mi experiencia en c no hay ninguna funcion nativa para comprobar lo que necesitas, debes crear una rutina para recorrer uno a uno los caracteres de la cadena y validar si se trata de un espacio o tabulador, aqui tienes un ejemplo:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    bool isStringValid(char * str) {
        bool isValid = true;
        int strlength = strlen(str);
        for ( int i = 0; i < strlength; i++ ) {
            // espacio, tabulador horizontal o vertical 
            if ( str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\t' || str[i] == '\v') {
                isValid = false;
                i = strlength;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    int main()
    {
        char* str = malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
        memset(str, 0, 30);
        sprintf(str, "Esto es una cadena de ejemplo");

        if (isStringValid(str)) {
            printf("La cadena es valida");
        } else {
            printf("La cadena es invalida");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```